# Do advanced aliens move planets through wormholes in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

The idea of moving planets through wormholes is a very outlandish and far fetched idea.

But it might solve a problem of scientific plausibility in *Star Trek* and other science fiction.

Western scientists accepted the biblical age of the Earth until 18th century geologists discovered that some rock formations took millions of years to form.  In the 19th century some geologists believed that the Earth could be a million times a million years old.

Astronomers calculated that the Sun could burn chemically for only a few thousand years.  It was later calculated that the Sun could shine from gravitational compression for only about 20 million years, while geologists claimed that the Earth was hundreds of millions of years old.

I have read that this paradox actually lead to a fight between an astronomer and a geologist at a scientific meeting.  And that violence could have been avoided if scientists had considered the possibility that super advanced aliens might have moved the Earth from star to star over the course of the Earth's life.

In the late 1930s the fusion processes that make stars shine were discovered and astrophysicists began to calculate that the Sun and the Earth could be billions of years old.

The Sun and the Earth are now believed to be about 4,600,000,000 years old.  The first life on Earth was probably about 4,100,000,000 years ago.  Photosynthesis  created an oxygen atmosphere on Earth about 2,300,000,000 years ago.  multicellular life appeared in the sea 1,500,000,000 years ago.  About 600,000,000 years ago atmospheric oxygen became abundant enough that an ozone layer as formed that protected against ultraviolet light.  Life later spread to the land.

The first known semi intelligent or fully intelligent species appeared a few million years ago if primates or tens of millions of years ago if cetaceans or proboscideans.

*Star Trek* and some other science fiction stories have a somewhat similar problem to the former astronomy-geology paradox that might be solved by having super advanced aliens move planets from star to star.

Of course planets have enormous mass and thus it should take enormous amounts of energy to move them.

But remember that it should take infinite energy to accelerate any object, even a single atom, to the speed of light. That is certainly more energy than it would take to move even the most massive planet at any speed less than light speed. So the warp drive and possibly also the impulse drive work by almost magically bypassing the constraints of Newtonian and relativistic physics and thus use far less than infinite amounts of energy.

If *Star Trek* spaceships can be moved at warp speed using less than infinite energy then presumably planets could be moved at warp speed by big enough warp engines - possibly using much more energy than starships but still much less than infinite energy.

And if an artificial wormhole is opened ahead of an orbiting planet, it will not take any energy to get the planet to enter the wormhole and emerge elsewhere, though creating the wormhole might take immense amounts of energy.

For example, in the *Lensman* series the Bergenholm inertialess drive can switch the inertia of an object on and off. A military tactic is to install giant Bergenholm drive units on a planet and move it into position near an enemy planet and then turn off the drive and restore inertia to the planet as it smashes into the enemy planet.

But since in the *Lensman* series a space fleet and a planet can be detected many thousands of light years away, a more advanced version of the tactic is to send the planets through a "hyperspatial tube", a sort of rough analogy to a wormhole, to appear inside the target solar system with little warning and little time for the defenders to react.

And it seems to me that sending planets through artificial wormholes actually could make *Star Trek* and some other science fiction stories more plausible.

In fact I think that anyone who has a mental list of, say, the 100 worst scientific problems with *Star Trek* can think of a scientific problem with *Star Trek* that super advanced aliens using wormholes to move planets from star system to star system would solve.

So how many of you agree that after thinking over various scientific problems with *Star Trek* that even though super advanced aliens sending planets though artificial wormholes from star to star is a very far fetched concept it could actually make *Star Trek* more plausible than it is?

Comment: Well... you want to apply the rules of one setting to a different one... to explain plausibility problems you have with this setting that you haven't even detailed or explained... and you're asking, what?  Whether it works?  Sorry, but voting to close.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to ask here. The question title (which is easily answerable with a "no") doesn't agree with the body of the question.

Comment: The warp drive doesn't magically avoid anything, they use Einstein's General Theory of Relativity.  The matter-antimatter reaction generates a plasma (large amount of energy) that is injected into the warp coils to generate the warp field, this allows the compression of space-time in front of the ship and expansion of it behind.  The ship doesn't hit or exceed the speed of light, it moves space-time around it while the ship itself travels at a much slower speed.

Comment: Warp drives are not 'magic' - they're actually a field of study that is considered plausible in the semi-near future, if certain models of the universe are correct. Look up the Alcubierre Drive.

Comment: There is a TNG Book called "Dyson Sphere" which talks about the mission back to the setting of the episode "Relics". Someone who remembers the book better can correct me, but I believe that a Neutron Star is sent through a Wormhole as a kind of weapon to destroy the Dyson Sphere.

Comment: Pulling a planet out of its orbit would cause havoc with other planets around that star. Talk about collateral damage!

Comment: I have made an edit to my question 02-08-17.

Answer (score 2):

**No.  Star Trek doesn't have planets in wormholes.**

Your "plausability problem" isn't a problem in Star Trek lore.  Impulse drive cannot reach "Warp One" specifically because it's a real-space drive system, and has to obey relativity.  Warp Drive works in Star Trek because the ship itself slips into "Subspace" while contained in the warp bubble;  the bubble itself would appear to move at faster than light, but the bubble itself doesn't actually exist in the universe.  Essentally, the mass of the ship is shifted into subspace, and therefore the speed of light (locally) is modified, allowing the ship to fly as if it was in a universe with different constants.

Only Q has the ability, in Star Trek, to actually move planets.  Even the Borg don't bother.  The largest object moved in Star Trek was the asteroidal moon of Bre'el IV in *Deja Q*.  In this episode, Q suggests changing the "gravitational constant of the universe" to alter the mass of the moon.  They can't do that, naturally, but La Forge realizes they could wrap a low level warp field around the moon, reducing IT'S gravitational constant, making it hopefully light enough to push.  Even this fails, because they can't protect Q and push the rock at the same time.

Maybe they could have eventually done it without blowing up, but Q makes it moot by snapping the moon into a stable orbit and making Data laugh.

So, no, Star Trek doesn't even have the ability to shift a planet into a wormhole.  They also don't have the ability to make stable wormholes from scratch.  They would need to find a wormhole, stabilize it, and then somehow move the planet in place... which nobody in Trek can do.

Comment: The prophets made a wormhole. Presumably that could have made it slightly larger?

Comment: The T'Kon Empire, according to legend, had the ability to move stars, so planets should be no problem. And did not Trelane move his planet by sheer will? I wouldn't be surprised if the other godlike races could move planets---or at least many of them---but this hasn't been shown in canon materials.

Comment: You are right about Trelane, @T-1000'sSon, but it's debated that Trelane might be a "young Qling" or the like, or at least in the Q class.  Additionally, while it appears that his planet is moving, it's also entirely possible (and my interpretation until I read the Telane article on Memory Alpha) it's an illusion or the Enterprise being reorientated.  I'll still stand by the statement that only The Q have been seen to actually have the power to move large objects in the Star Trek continunity.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon the Tkon empire, otherwise, was able to move star systems in **legend**, but we never see them do it, or evidence of it having been done, on screen. Only legends passed down through 600,000 years of history. We do know they had a huge span of Empire. According to non-canon books, the Tkon did have the ability to attempt to switch their sun with another one (not the whole star system), but that project failed due to Q-class meddling, and we never got to see it actually work.

Comment: @Valorum I do not believe the Prophets are ever proven to have **created** the wormhole, only to have **stabilized** it.  They had the ability to seal it up, and without their efforts it would destabilize.  If this is true, then they can't "create" a wormhole to move a planet; they could only stabilize a sufficiently located wormhole and hope the planet falls through.

Comment: The Prophet's Temple is also a different wormhole than the "wormholes" created by warp engine imbalances.  Those wormholes are unstable, and while an asteroid was seen in the wormhole, it was not being intentionally moved;  it was just an object the Enterprise had to avoid.

Comment: @Zoey Any statement can be questioned. I think, though, that unless there is good reason, statements should be regarded as true. There's no reason given in any episode or movie to doubt the claims made about the T'kon Empire, so I think that they should be given the benefit of the doubt. I mean, we never saw the Douwd actually kill the Husnock---perhaps he lied---but most people accept his statement as true because nothing in the episode (or any other canon material) contradicts it.